# How to make sure the program runs the right instruction when I hit some key

Tags: c++, forms, android-edittext, keypress

I am making a simple program using borland c++ (my college task, :D), I want to do some instruction when I hit enter after I insert an id to editText1,

```
if(Key == 13){
  ShowMessage("u hit enter");//just test
```

that is the editText1 OnKeyPress event instruction, but when I hit enter, the program executes the other instruction, thats the instruction from other button.

Comment: You will need to show full code, how do you set up OnKeyPress and what is this other instruction?

Comment: You are creating a GUI, not a console app.  The Enter key is reserved to operate the default button of the window, like the OK button.  Consider getting used to the Tab key and creating UI that is non-modal.

Comment: C++Builder?  While that product touches a warm spot in my heart, it's not really doing you any favors to be learning such an old version of c++ either, unfortunately.

Comment: @mnistic
'other instruction' is yaaa, other instruction
that must be run by other object that in my case is a button

i have edittext1, the code is : 
if(Key == 13){
  ShowMessage("u hit enter");//just test

and i have a button, and the code is to show  message "test", but when i hit enter, the output is "test", not "u hit enter"